# How to set the browser url as connection string name in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string

How can I set the browser url as the connection string in my project. I used this code in my project page load but am getting null exception.

```
string connectionstring = string.Empty;
SqlConnection con1;
connectionstring = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
connectionstring = connectionstring.Replace("http://", "");
connectionstring = connectionstring.Replace("/Default.aspx", "");
con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionstring].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: If you're storing the Conn string in the `web.config`, then there will only be a finite (if not one) set of connection strings.. Why not do it explicitly? I mean, I don't see how you need a totally separate domain-controlled database for every domain - Unless you're creating the same website and using it across multiple domains..?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the domain use:

```
var connectionstring = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToLower();
```

You could also put it in your query string: 
site.com/Default.aspx?con=myConnection

```
var connectionstring = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["con"];
```

Its also a good idea to check the connection name you extract from url (Is it valid, does the user have permission to use that database and so on)